# Magento 2 - Git workflow

Tags: magento2, git, versioning

I am brand new with Magento 2 and I've been thinking about version control (git specifically) in M2. We know that installing modules is a critical thing in Magento. So, I would like to know if there is pattern of version control for Magento 2. If not, I would like to know about your workflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 doesn't require any special version control method, all the changes from M1 to M2 should take place during the deployment process (the vendor/ folder specifically).

My personal favorite and what we try to emulate at my workplace is [Git Flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html).

Comment: Ok, when you are working alone, git works very well. For instance, if I am working with another member, I Install an extension and push to remote. The other member does not receive the changes and/or his installation breaks, I think this is because the database is not the same, and the extension makes changes in database. How do you deal with extension installations, working with a team?

Comment: It's important that all team members agree and adhere to the Git Flow process. Only push/merge changes that are tested locally. It will be the other team members' responsibility to ensure their branch is brought up to speed.